# Removing a sentence from a text in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to format a text-column in the dataframe in a following way:

In entries where the last character of a string is a colon ":" I want to delete the last sentence in this text i.e. a substring starting from a character after the last ".", "?" or "!" and finishing on that colon.

Example df:

```
index    text
1        Trump met with Putin. Learn more here:
2        New movie by Christopher Nolan! Watch here:
3        Campers: Get ready to stop COVID-19 in its tracks!
4        London was building a bigger rival to the Eiffel Tower. Then it all went wrong.
```

after formatting should look like this:

```
index    text
1        Trump met with Putin.
2        New movie by Christopher Nolan!
3        Campers: Get ready to stop COVID-19 in its tracks!
4        London was building a bigger rival to the Eiffel Tower. Then it all went wrong.
```

Comment: s/(?<=\.).*?:$//

Comment: I updated the question to not only consider the case where the sentence ends on a full period

Comment: regex is brittle especially when you have no control over how the text is generated. You will quickly find your regex case set expanding if you want to parse all your rows successfully.

Comment: regex is almost always brittle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets do it with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Fl3ci6/1) to have more problems

```
df.text = df.text.str.replace(r"(?<=[.!?])[^.!?]*:\s*$", "", regex=True)
```

now `df.text.tolist()` is

```
['Trump met with Putin.',
 'New movie by Christopher Nolan!',
 'Campers: Get ready to stop COVID-19 in its tracks!',
 'London was building a bigger rival to the Eiffel Tower. Then it all went wrong.',
 "I don't want to do a national lockdown again. If #coronavirus continues to 'progress' in the UK."]
```

variable lookbehind ftw

##### On regex:

```
(?<=[.!?])
```

This is a "lookbehind". It doesnt physically match anything but asserts something, which is that there must be *something* before what follows this. That something happens to be a character class here `[.!?]` which means *either* . or ! or ?.

```
[^.!?]*
```

Again we have a character class with square brackets. But now we have a caret `^` as the first which means that we want everything *except* those in the character class. So any character other than . or ! or ? will do.

The `*` after the character class is 0-or-more quantifier. Meaning, the "any character but .?!" can be found as many times as possible.

So far, we start matching either . or ? or !, and this character is behind a stream of characters which could be "anything but .?!". So we assured we match after the *last* sentence with this "anything but" because it can't match .?! on the way anymore.

```
:\s*$
```

With `:`, we say that the 0-or-more stream above is to stop whenever it sees `:` (if ever; if not, no replacement happens as desired).

The `\s*` after it is to allow some possible (again, 0 or more due to *) spaces (\s means space) after the `:`. You can remove that if you are certain there shall not be any space after `:`.

Lastly we have `$`: this matches the end of string (nothing physical, but positional). So we are sure that the string ends with `:` followed optionally by some spaces.

Comment: I updated the question to keep in mind that the sentence doesn't need to end on a full period all the time. This works for periods only

Comment: i put \s* to consider possible spaces after : at the very end

Comment: This works as intended, thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After some testing it seems like this method doesn't delete 1 sentence but multiple sentences. String like this: "I don't want to do a national lockdown again. If #coronavirus continues to 'progress' in the UK. Read more here:", is replaced by: "I don't want to do a national lockdown again.", whereas it should keep the 2nd sentence

Comment: @JanMarczak ok I made an edit. Now it will replace after the last punctuation character which is . or ? or !. maybe it works

Comment: Seems to work for now, thanks. Would you mind explaining a bit the regex you wrote?

Comment: @JanMarczak Sure. I tried to explain. By the way, I had put a link from regex101 from the beginning and thats why I didnt detail the regex as that website has some explainations. I hope together with those it is somewhat more clear now what regex is doing

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using `sent_tokenize` from the [NLTK tokenize API](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) which IMO is the idiomatic way of tokenizing sentences

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
(df['text'].map(nltk.sent_tokenize)
           .map(lambda sent: ' '.join([s for s in sent if not s.endswith(':')])))

index
1                                Trump met with Putin.
2                      New movie by Christopher Nolan.
3    Campers: Get ready to stop COVID-19 in its tra...
4    London was building a bigger rival to the Eiff...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

You might have to handle NaNs appropriately with a preceeding `fillna('')` call if your column contains those.

In list form the output looks like this:

```
['Trump met with Putin.',
 'New movie by Christopher Nolan.',
 'Campers: Get ready to stop COVID-19 in its tracks!',
 'London was building a bigger rival to the Eiffel Tower. Then it all went wrong.']
```

Note that NLTK needs to be pip-installed.

Comment: your output doesnt show all which kind of takes the fun aWay

Comment: @doesitmatter oh yeah.... something to do with my terminal's display options. There, added a listified version of the output ;-)

Comment: what python version are you on that you are using join([ instead of join(

Comment: @doesitmatter it doesn't matter. [It's actually slightly faster to use join with a list comprehension than a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087)

Comment: i prefer join( over that ugly join([ anytime sorry

Comment: To each their own. Besides I'd leave that up to the OP as to what to use, this is my personally preferred method.

Comment: I am having some troubles with NLTK library so I can't really test it properly. Thank you very much anyway

Comment: @JanMarczak what are the "some troubles"?